# How to get to London Heathrow from Shepherd's Bush in light of possible Tube strike?

Tags: london, lhr

My flight is at 8:40am Saturday. I would like to arrive by 6:40am.

My proposed route is below.

- 283 bus to Hammersmith Bus Station
- Walk to Hammersmith
- Piccadilly line to Heathrow Terminals 1-2-3 Underground Station

Is this the best way to go? I've also heard that some of the lines are striking currently. Could this route be affected? If so, what alternatives are there?

Comment: What time is your flight, and which day of the week?

Comment: how early is early? The tube may not even be running yet...

Comment: Flight is on Saturday at 8:40am. It's also international, so I'd like to be there at 6:40am.

Comment: Where initially are you going from? Where are you planning to get on bus 283?

Comment: Planning on picking up the bus from Uxbridge Rd. at Shepherd's Bush Market. Using the tfl.gov.uk site, this is my results page - https://www.tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/results?IsAsync=true&JpType=publictransport&From=Shepherd%27s+Bush+Market&FromGeolocation=&ToGeolocation=&ViaGeolocation=&To=Heathrow+Terminals+1-3&TimeIs=departing&Date=20140823&Time=0530&Via=&NationalSearch=false&JourneyPreference=leasttime&Mode=tube&Mode=bus&Mode=dlr&Mode=river-bus&Mode=tram&Mode=cable-car&Mode=overground&Mode=national-rail&Mode=coach&MaxWalkingMinutes=40&FromId=1000204&ToId=1000105

Comment: If you can walk to the eastern end of Shepherd's Bush Green there is a bus stop where there are half a dozen different buses that go via Hammersmith (including the 283). Anything going to Putney, Wandsworth, Barnes etc. All the buses you would have taken go via this stop but you pick up a few more that come from the Holland Park direction. Get off at the Hammersmith bus station itself because inside is a direct staircase down to the Piccadilly line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps has a pretty good knowledge of the London public transport.  [This map](https://www.google.es/maps/dir/Shepherd's+Bush,+London+W12,+UK/Heathrow+Airport,+Greater+London+TW6,+United+Kingdom/@51.498313,-0.3206578,11z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m19!4m18!1m5!1m1!1s0x48760fd28997cb07:0x6c79a6e5e0483766!2m2!1d-0.22305!2d51.504746!1m5!1m1!1s0x48767234cdc56de9:0x8fe7535543f64167!2m2!1d-0.454296!2d51.470022!2m3!6e5!7e2!8j1408776000!3e3!5i3?hl=en) will show you several options, which will all have you arriving before 6:40am on Saturday (tomorrow--although any Saturday ought to be roughly the same).

The one that looks the most attractive to me is the last one, which is to take the 295 bus (although 283 may be just as good) to Hammersmith, then the Picadilly line to LHR.  It includes only 6 minutes of walking.

On the London Tube web site you can see the [current status](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/tube-dlr-overground/status/) as well as [*planned* outages](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/forms/12392.aspx). Whether a strike-caused outage would be posted early enough to help you make your travel plans, I have no idea.  I suggest waking up a bit early and checking, just in case. Then at least you'll have the option to call a taxi in time, if the worst should happen.

Comment: Thanks. One of my main concerns is regarding the tube strike that's happening now. Today the central line is down. Just hoping the Picadilly line will be unaffected tomorrow, but not sure where (if it's posted at all) to get that sort of information.

Comment: @Blake: Answer updated with a little more info on that... sorry I can't offer any greater assurances, though.

Comment: Seems to be as much information as I can possibly get at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way is easybus.

The trip last for 30-75mins, and cost £1.95+ (cost more if book late)

The timetable is not balance but at least 1 bus departure every hour